# Notify FUNCTION in PGSQL to pass column values to C#

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I have a `TRIGGER` created in `PGSQL` to NOTIFY my **c# app** when a new ROW is created in my `TABLE` with a matching condition on a column value.

FUNCTION to send **`msgfail`** to c#:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION notify_fail() RETURNS TRIGGER AS '
BEGIN
NOTIFY msgfail;
RETURN NULL;
END;
'LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

TRIGGER to call the FUNCTION when a new ROW is INSERT:

```
CREATE TRIGGER failtrigger AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
ON jm FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE notify_fail();
WHEN (NEW.message_string LIKE '%error%')
EXECUTE PROCEDURE notify_fail();
```

This works fine so far.

**Question :** I want to modify the function to return contents of one or more columns back to the c# application.

```
If a new ROW is INSERT then call FUNCTION. Inside FUNCTION: RETURN Column1.
```

Is this possible?

**Npgsql.dll version :  2.0.11.91**

Comment: I don't think this is supported in nPgSQL yet. You're looking for the *payload* feature of `NOTIFY`. What you can do as a workaround is `INSERT` the information into a table and when your application receives the notify it can `DELETE FROM ... RETURNING` the table contents.

Comment: Thanks Craig. While does not directly get me what I want, copying to another table and querying that is a neat workaround. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not supported by npgsql as Craig notes.

One set of tools you may find helpful for managing this is http://pgxn.org/dist/pg_message_queue/

It isn't fully functional in terms of supporting multiple subscribers in high performance configurations but it is simple and works quite well for getting arbitrary data to notify listeners.